# How to create a custom ToolTip with an image?

Tags: c#, custom-controls, tooltip, system.drawing

I want to create a custome tooltip with the folllowing contents:

- Image at the top right corner
- Text at the left side

Currently I have a class who inherits from the ToolTip Objekt.

```
class CustomToolTip : ToolTip
{
    public CustomToolTip()
    {
        this.OwnerDraw = true;
        this.Popup += new PopupEventHandler(this.OnPopup);
        this.Draw += new DrawToolTipEventHandler(this.OnDraw);
    }

    private void OnPopup(object sender, PopupEventArgs e)
    {
        e.ToolTipSize = new Size(200, 100);
    }

    private void OnDraw(object sender, DrawToolTipEventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

But I don't know what to do in the "OnDraw-Event" to show a Image with text.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please Try [GDI+](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms533802%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnPaint(e);
    Image img = Image.FromFile("C:\filepath\filename.jpg");
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(img, 0, 0);
    var YourTipTextPoint = new Point(0,0);
    e.Graphics.DrawString("Hello World", SystemFonts.DefaultFont, Brushes.Black, YourTipTextPoint); 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

have a look on this http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42050/ToolTip-With-Image-C
should be explained enough

```
myImageRectangle = Rectangle.Inflate(myToolTipRectangle, -BORDER_THICKNESS, -BORDER_THICKNESS);
Image toolTipImage = Image.FromFile(filepath);        
if (toolTipImage != null)
    {
        myImageRectangle.Width = 200;
        myTextRectangle = new Rectangle(myImageRectangle.Right, myImageRectangle.Top, (myToolTipRectangle.Width - myImageRectangle.Right), myImageRectangle.Height);
        myTextRectangle.Location = new Point(myImageRectangle.Right, myImageRectangle.Top);
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(myBackColorBrush, myTextRectangle);
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(toolTipImage, myImageRectangle);
        e.Graphics.DrawString(e.ToolTipText, myFont, 
        myTextBrush, myTextRectangle, myTextFormat);
    }
```

Comment: As much as your answer is appreciated, please refrain from posting "link only" answers. The link may go obsolete in the future, rendering your answer useless. Consider editing your answer by adding the gist of the link's article, posting some example code if it's not too long.