# Question about toolTips with an Image in C#

Tags: c#, forms, winforms, tooltip

So i am making a program with a interactive periodic table but I am really new to programmin especially in C#, And I want to have a toolTip on every element that shows its picture and some details. But i dont know how to make a tooltip with an image. I need the code for Mouse Enter and Mouse Leave Event. All the Elements are Buttons Btw.
THIS IS THE CODE I HAVE

```
    private void Element_H_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void Element_H_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void toolTip1_Popup(object sender, PopupEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void toolTip1_Draw(object sender, DrawToolTipEventArgs e)
    {
        
    }
}
class CustomToolTip : ToolTip // This code i copied from someone online but i dont even know where to paste it or how to use it//
{
    public CustomToolTip()
    {
        this.OwnerDraw = true;
        this.Popup += new PopupEventHandler(this.OnPopup);
        this.Draw += new DrawToolTipEventHandler(this.OnDraw);
    }

    private void OnPopup(object sender, PopupEventArgs e)
    {
        e.ToolTipSize = new Size(200, 100);
    }

    private void OnDraw(object sender, DrawToolTipEventArgs e)
    {
       
    }
```

This is How the Hover Should Look
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RKguS.png

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a custom ToolTip with an image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16099995/how-to-create-a-custom-tooltip-with-an-image)

Comment: Thats the thing i was reading before posting a question but i dont understand where i need to paste the code I Told you i am new with this

Comment: Yersss, I'm not sure that using a ToolTip really gives you much benefit here over just having an info panel that you set visible and locate near wherever the mouse coords are in the image

Comment: Right, the answer is a generic code to paint image in controls `Paint`. For tooltips refer to [example on msdn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.drawtooltipeventargs). In principle it's the same code using  `e.Graphics.DrawImage()`. Don't just *paste the code*, always study each new thing you was told.

Comment: [ToolTip With Image C#](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42050/ToolTip-With-Image-C).

Answer (score 2):

I have not used WinForms for a long time, so apologies in advance if there is better ways of doing this. As the answers in the comments have suggested we need to make our own ToolTip for this.

I have done this like so, this is a very quick knock up you can work out the maths to make things line up properly, add more information and change colours fonts etc if you wish.

I'd recommend you put this in its own file. (Right-click the project file from the solution explorer and go to 'Add' --> 'Class'

```
public class CustomToolTip : ToolTip
{
    public CustomToolTip()
    {
        this.OwnerDraw = true;
        this.Popup += new PopupEventHandler(this.OnPopup);
        this.Draw += new DrawToolTipEventHandler(this.OnDraw);
    }

    private void OnPopup(object sender, PopupEventArgs e)
    {
        e.ToolTipSize = new Size(200, 100);
    }

    private void OnDraw(object sender, DrawToolTipEventArgs e)
    {
        Graphics g = e.Graphics;

        LinearGradientBrush b = new LinearGradientBrush(e.Bounds, Color.DarkGray, Color.LightGray, 45f);
        g.FillRectangle(b, e.Bounds);

        //Now we need to get the element information..
        var element = PeriodicTableHelper.Elements.Where(_ => _.Symbol == e.ToolTipText).First();

        var img = Image.FromFile(element.ImagePath);
        g.DrawImage(img, 2, 2, 32, e.Bounds.Height - 4);

        //Name
        g.DrawString("Name: ", new Font(e.Font, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.White, new PointF(e.Bounds.X + 38, e.Bounds.Y + 2));
        g.DrawString(element.Name, new Font(e.Font, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.White, new PointF(e.Bounds.X + 80, e.Bounds.Y + 2));

        //Melting point
        g.DrawString("Melting Point: ", new Font(e.Font, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.White, new PointF(e.Bounds.X + 38, e.Bounds.Y + 20));
        g.DrawString(element.MeltingPoint.ToString(), new Font(e.Font, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.White, new PointF(e.Bounds.X + 120, e.Bounds.Y + 20));

        //Atomic number
        g.DrawString("Atomic Number: ", new Font(e.Font, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.White, new PointF(e.Bounds.X + 38, e.Bounds.Y + 40));
        g.DrawString(element.AtomicNumber.ToString(), new Font(e.Font, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.White, new PointF(e.Bounds.X + 140, e.Bounds.Y + 40));

        b.Dispose();
    }
}
```

This has a dependency on a class called PeriodicTableHelper which is basically a collection of all the possible elements, I assume you have something like this already but  here's my very basic version. Again, I would have this in it's own file.

```
public class PeriodicTableElement
{
    public string Symbol { get; set; }
    public int AtomicNumber { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal MeltingPoint { get; set; }
    public string ImagePath { get; set; }
}

public static class PeriodicTableHelper
{
    public static List<PeriodicTableElement> Elements { get; }
    static PeriodicTableHelper()
    {
        //Load up the elements however you want to do this. Maybe deserialse a JSON file?
        //Also you wouldn't have hardcoded file paths like this obviously!
        //You could use a Bitmap type instead and have the image in the project resources
        Elements = new List<PeriodicTableElement>();

        Elements.Add(new PeriodicTableElement
        {
            Symbol = "Mg",
            AtomicNumber = 12,
            Name = "Magnesium",
            MeltingPoint = 923,
            ImagePath = @"D:\Downloads\magnesium.png"
        });

        Elements.Add(new PeriodicTableElement
        {
            Symbol = "Ca",
            AtomicNumber = 20,
            Name = "Calcium",
            MeltingPoint = 1115,
            ImagePath = @"D:\Downloads\calcium.png"
        });
    }
}
```

Now we need to wire up the buttons to this class. Which I have done like this. This goes in the Form code.

```
private CustomToolTip _toolTip; 

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    _toolTip = new CustomToolTip();
    SetupToolTip();
}

private void SetupToolTip()
{
    _toolTip.SetToolTip(btnMagnesium, "Mg");
    _toolTip.SetToolTip(btnCalcium, "Ca");
}
```

Hopefully this gives you a starting point. Any questions / issues leave a comment below. :)

The result looks something like this. Ignore the image, I choose a random one from my download folder ha.

[image: ToolTip Result]

Comment: Hmm it wouldve been nice if i understood anythign i said i am rly new with C especially C# i am still learning C++ but i gotta create a program for a project and i dont understand where i need to put your code my code looks like this
https://imgur.com/NmvLaDd

Comment: Technically there is no right or wrong place to put these. I have updated the answer. The CustomToolTip and PeriodicTableHelper I would put in separate files within your project.